# Which SATA revision does device support?

Tags: ssd, sata, ahci

How to tell which SATA revision is supported by a device (either motherboard or SSD drive) within Linux or Windows or any other way?

[Samsung PM893/PM897 SSD specification](https://www.truenas.com/community/attachments/samsung-sata-ssd-pm893-pm897-pdf.72077/) explicitly says SATA 3.3 compliant.

However, most manufacturers just state SATA III so you do not really know if it is SATA 3.0 back from 2008 or SATA 3.5 from 2020. All of these are 6Gbit/s of course.

One way of finding some information is to check device supported features. [CrystalDiskInfo](https://crystalmark.info/en/software/crystaldiskinfo/) reports that SSD supports DevSleep. [DevSleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevSlp) was introduced in SATA 3.2 back in 2013. This SSD is SATA 3.2 compliant at least.

And lastly, does SATA 3.X minor revision updates depend on hardware, firmware or drivers?
I was trying to get a clue from [SATA AHCI specification](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/serial-ata/serial-ata-ahci-spec-rev1-3-1.html), but did not find anything.

Comment: SATA 3.3 is SATA III. If the drive says SATA 3.3 then it's SATA III. Why is the specific revision of the SATA III standard important?  When was the drive in question manufactured?

Comment: @Ramhound because SATA3.1+ revisions introduce improvements which should benefit SSDs. The drive in question was manufactured between 03/09/2019 and 17/12/2021. Manufacturing date is not an indication of manufacturer updating device capabilities though.

Comment: The thing is, "compliant" does not mean it supports every new features *defined* in the updated standard. While it *could* indeed mandate devices to implement certain features, I highly doubt that it would be the case of the majority of them. In other words, if you desire a certain feature, just read the whitepaper / spec of the device you are considering. If the vendor choose not to tell you explicitly, your best shot would be to conduct research online (reviews or similar). The revision is nothing but a reference of which document the vendor referenced to when they make the drive.

Comment: @igor You could try [HWiNFO](https://www.hwinfo.com/) to see if that reports the version - I don't have any SATA drives installed to check.

Comment: If your goal is to find out whether a certain feature is implemented in a SATA drive you currently possess, then `hdparm -I` is probably the best you can get in Linux. (It should also tell you the revision. So does `smartctl`, IIRC.)